# JXTreeTable RowFilter implementation

Tags: java, swingx

I'll try to implement RowFilter for JXTreeTable, but it does not work. My implementation is smth like this:

```
public class CustomRowFilter extends RowFilter<TableModel, Integer> {
@Override
public boolean include(Entry entry) {
    if (entry.getValueCount() == 3) {
        Integervalue1 = (Integer) entry.getValue(1);
        Integervalue2 = (Integer) entry.getValue(2);
        if (value1.equals(value2)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

}

Can somebody tell me where is my mistake? May be JXTreeTable does not support filtering?

Thnx in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sorting/filtering is not supported in JXTreeTable

https://community.oracle.com/thread/2167209?tstart=0